# XML parsing gives NullPointerException Error with Asynctask

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, android-asynctask

I am using XML parser to extract few things off a website and I have the code inside an Asynctask. For some reason I keep getting the NullPointerException, why?

**What's causing the error, and how do you fix it?**  I appreciate your time.

**This is the LogCat**

```
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thenewlistivew/com.thenewlistivew.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:976)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at com.thenewlistivew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4486)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
02-08 23:34:08.835: E/AndroidRuntime(28103):    ... 11 more
```

**My AsyncTask Code:**

```
private class ShowDialogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // update the UI immediately after the task is executed
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
            // looping through all song nodes <song>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
                map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                songsList.add(map);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
            adapter = new LazyAdapter(MainActivity.this, songsList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

**OnCreate Method code**

```
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute();

        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi the issue seems to be in onCreate method of your activity, could you please edit your question with the onCreate method.

Comment: I added it, check again.

Comment: where are you initializing the "list"? Please do the following initialize the your list "list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);" before "list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have --

`list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()`

but you never initialize `list`

Move this line to your `onCreate()` --

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Comment: Check my code again, I initialized it. I just didn't include it here.

Comment: @Ammar I still do not see an initialization.  `ListView list;` is a declaration, but does not actually give `list` a value, and thus will default to `null`.  You need to give it a known value, did you try putting the line I suggested in your `onCreate` before setting your click listener?

Comment: I initialized it and now it works fine. Thank you for pointing that out, I misunderstood you at first. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ammar No problem.  Terminology can be tricky. You are welcome.